# convert JSON object into REST API

Tags: json, rest, api, generator

Is there any tool or library available which can generate REST API from JSON file. Independent of language. On the basis of JSON object generate REST API.

for Example:

```
{  
  "name": "set",
  "type":"function",
  "inputs":[{"name":"num", "type":"int"}]
  "output":[{"name":"value", "type":"int"}]
}
```

Clarification:

The JSON file will contain function and its detail like name, input argument and output(return) parameters.
So according to this JSON file, REST API methods should be generated for the function described in the JSON.
For ex: A function named **set** and it is accepting one argument num of int type and returning a value of int type.
Is it possible to generate REST API method for this function like GET and POST from the knowledge of JSON file only?

Hope it clears the question!

Comment: function code is just for the reference that what JSON is representing

Answer (score 3):

You can use swagger (https://swagger.io/, https://generator.swagger.io/)

It can generate API (supports different languages) from openAPI spec file.

The spec file can be json or yaml.

You should transform your json to spec-specific json format.